# Any alternative to fstat?

Tags: c++, c

Is there any alternative to using `fstat()` function if you just need is the file size and creation date?
I know we can use `ftell()` to get the file size but I want the creation time and date too. The reason I dont want to use `fstat()` is that it takes a lot of time if the file list is long.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: `fstat` gives you the size too, so using that information should cut the number of operations.

Comment: fstat requires an open file.  If you are going to open the files in the list anyway fstat is a good choice.  If not then use stat().  And.  Either of these calls is as fast as it gets for finding file metadata. If all you want is file metadata.

Comment: `fstat` is generally faster than `fseek`+`ftell` for getting the file size (one system call vs. two).  If your directory is too big and you're using a filesystem that performs poorly with big directories, the `open` will be slow, but you need that for either.

Comment: Another comment on this: If you're using a Linux with a EXT filesystem (any version) sort your files by inode before doing stat or fstat on each one. This makes the metadata requests happen in order on the disk and is faster.

Comment: Thanks very much for all the comments. 
I was using fstat() for accessing the metadata and get the creation time/date. I was thinking along the lines of getting only the size and the creation time/date instead of the big structure that the fstat() function returns. From the responses, I think that there are no other better alternatives.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: It's an implementation detail whether `fseek+ftell` takes two system calls. E.g. on Windows, `SetFilePointerEx` will seek and return the new position in a single call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is open, use `fstat` if you just have the file name and don't care about opening the file, use `stat`. It's as fast as it can get. Whatever other function you'd use will use `stat` or `fstat` internally or at least their equivalents inside the kernel. Those system calls need to read in the metadata from the filesystem and if that's not in the cache it will go to disk and take time. There's no way around it.

Comment: +1. If fstat is slow this can be if the directory i-node is too big. Use smaller directory entries can speed up reading the metadata in the i-node.

Comment: Thanks very much for all the comments. 
I was using fstat() for accessing the metadata and get the creation time/date. I was thinking along the lines of getting only the size and the creation time/date instead of the big structure that the fstat() function returns. From the responses, I think that there are no other better alternatives.